# nose-doctest module fixture before module is imported

Tags: python, testing, nose, doctest

I use nose for test collection and I also want to use its doctest plugin. I have a module that needs a fixture in order to be importable. Therefore, I cannot use nose's module fixtures, since they are loaded from the module under test. Is there a way to specify module fixtures for nose-doctest outside of the module?

For some use-cases, an option would be to detect being run under doctest and to apply the fixture at the beginning of the module. I'd be interested to hear answers for this use-case as-well.

However, there are situations where this cannot work: When the import fails due to a `SyntaxError`, no module code is ever run. In my case, I'm mostly developing code that is both compatible with python 2 and python 3 (without `2to3`). There are a few python 3 specific modules however, which simply should not be inspected at all by nose, when run under python 2. What would my best option be here?

**EDIT: MWE** (for the `SyntaxError` situation)

I have a package with many small modules, some of them use python 3 syntax.
Here's the package structure:

```
~/pckg/
  __init__.py
  py3only.py
  ... (other modules)
  tests/
    test_py3only.py
```

Some tests are written as `unittest.TestCase`, but I also want the code examples in the docstrings tested. `~/pckg/__init__.py` is empty.

~/pckg/py3only.py:

```
def fancy_py3_func(a:"A function argument annotation (python 3 only syntax)"):
    """ A function using fancy syntax doubling it's input.

    >>> fancy_py3_func(4)
    8
    """
    return a*2
```

~/pckg/tests/test_py3only.py:

```
import sys, unittest

def setup_module():
    if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
        raise unittest.SkipTest("py3only unavailable on python "+sys.version)

class TestFancyFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bruteforce(self):
        from pckg.py3only import fancy_py3_func
        for k in range(10):
            self.assertEqual(fancy_py3_func(k),2*k)
```

Testing on python 3, everything gets tested and passes (run from the enclosing folder, e.g. `~`):

```
~ nosetests3 -v --with-doctest pckg
Doctest: pckg.py3only.fancy_py3_func ... ok
test_bruteforce (test_py3only.TestFancyFunc) ... ok
```

On python 2, the module fixture of `~/pckg/tests/test_py2only.py` properly detects the situation and skips the test. However, we get a `SyntaxError` from `~/pckg/py3only.py`:

```
~ nosetests -v --with-doctest pckg 
Failure: SyntaxError (invalid syntax (py3only.py, line 1)) ... ERROR
SKIP: py3only unavailable on python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
```

A function similar to `~/pckg/tests/test_py3only.py:setup_module()` could solve that problem, if I could get `nose` to run that code before it's doctest plugin even attempts to import that module.

It looks like my best bet is to write a proper top-level test script that handles the collection of the tests...

Comment: Module cannot be imported without X or Y smells bad, it means, for example that neither `pydoc` nor `pylint` can be used on your code. Changing module at import time because it is under test kindof defeats the whole point of testing, doesn't it?

Comment: I have essentially two cases: Missing _optional_ external dependencies, and modules using new python 3 syntax, tested under python 2. In both cases, testing is essentially vain, the modules are unavailable. I want to suppress the test failures and maybe replace them with messages, that some part of the library is unavailable due to missing dependencies.

Comment: `nosetests -v --with-doctest pckg` you let Python 2 see Python 3 code because you run `--with-doctest` from the top dir. Run the tests both unittest and doctest from `tests` folder. For doctest to succeed extract it to plain text file as I've done so that you can conditionally import.

Comment: > A function similar to ~/pckg/tests/test_py3only.py:setup_module() could solve that problem. `setup_` functions are for unittest.

Comment: I do not want to extract the doctests into a text file: They form part of the docstring. I want to test them to ensure that they are correct. `setup_` functions form part of the so called `fixtures`, and I was hoping there was a way to specify them for docstring embedded doctests. I guess that was vain.

Comment: `nosetests` has `-I REGEX` option to ignore files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific test files, directories, classes or methods can be excluded using [nose-exclude](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-exclude) nose plugin. It has `--exclude-*` options.

To handle missing modules, you have to patch `sys.modules` using `mock`.

F.e, There's a `Calc` class in `mycalc` module, but I don't have access to it because it's missing. And there are two more modules, `mysuper_calc` and `mysuper_calc3`, the latter is Python 3 specific. These two modules import `mycalc` and `mysuper_calc3` shouldn't be tested under Python 2. How to doctest them out of module, that's in plain text file? I assume this is OP's situation.

calc/mysuper_calc3.py

```
from sys import version_info
if version_info[0] != 3:
    raise Exception('Python 3 required')
from mycalc import Calc
class SuperCalc(Calc):
    '''This class implements an enhanced calculator
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        Calc.__init__(self)

    def add(self, n, m):
        return Calc.add(self, n, m)
```

calc/mysuper_calc.py

```
from mycalc import Calc

class SuperCalc(Calc):
    '''This class implements an enhanced calculator
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        Calc.__init__(self)

    def add(self, n, m):
        return Calc.add(self, n, m)
```

Now to mock out `mycalc`,

```
>>> from mock import Mock, patch
>>> mock = Mock(name='mycalc')
```

Module `mycalc` has class `Calc` which has method `add`. I test `SuperCalc` instance `add` method with `2+3`.

```
>>> mock.Calc.add.return_value = 5
```

Now patch `sys.modules` and `mysuper_calc3` can be conditionally imported within the `with` block.

```
>>> with patch.dict('sys.modules',{'mycalc': mock}):
...     from mysuper_calc import SuperCalc
...     if version_info[0] == 3:
...         from mysuper_calc3 import SuperCalc
```

calc/doctest/mysuper_calc_doctest.txt

```
>>> from sys import version_info
>>> from mock import Mock, patch
>>> mock = Mock(name='mycalc')
>>> mock.Calc.add.return_value = 5

>>> with patch.dict('sys.modules',{'mycalc': mock}):
...     from mysuper_calc import SuperCalc
...     if version_info[0] == 3:
...         from mysuper_calc3 import SuperCalc
>>> c = SuperCalc()
>>> c.add(2,3)
5
```

The file `mysuper_calc_doctest.txt` has to be alone in its own directory otherwise `nosetests` searches for `doctest` in non-test modules.

```
PYTHONPATH=.. nosetests --with-doctest --doctest-extension=txt --verbosity=3
```

Doctest: mysuper_calc_doctest.txt ... ok

---

Ran 1 test in 0.038s

OK

A wrapper around `nosetests` to detect Python 3 which passes .py files without syntax errors to `nosetests`

mynosetests.py

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from glob import glob

f_list = []

py_files = glob('*py')
try:
    py_files.remove(sys.argv[0])
except ValueError:
    pass

for py_file in py_files:
    try:
        exec open(py_file)
    except SyntaxError:
        continue
    else:
        f_list.append(py_file)

proc = Popen(['nosetests'] + sys.argv[1:] + f_list,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print('%s\n%s' % proc.communicate())
sys.exit(proc.returncode)
```

Comment: Sure, patching `sys.modules` with mock modules would be one possible action that my fixture could do in order to make them importable. The problem is, where do I place this fixture code, such that `nose` runs it before `nose-doctest` tries to import the module?

Comment: Also, while `nose-exclude`would allow me to exclude the files with python 3 syntax from the tests, it only allows to do so either statically from the `node.cfg` file or from the command line. I would have preferred to let a fixture decide on skipping, since I only want to skip when testing python 2, but not when testing python 3, and without any manual interaction.

Comment: 'fixture' in your context is unclear. Show us some example code, describing both of your situation, `nose` can't import and 'fixutre' decide on skipping.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed edit. In my case, the doctests are embedded in the docstrings within the modules. I depend on `nose-doctest` to gather them. Thus, when they get run, it is too late to do the mock patching, as the module is already imported. However, in your case, `doctest` does not seem to inspect your modules for docstrings, otherwise you'd get an exception when importing `mysuper_calc3`. I'll post a minimal working example (should have from the beginning of course).

Comment: You can patch right in the module which has missing imports.

Comment: Which indeed solves my first problem, but not the `SyntaxError`. (In fact, I just skip by raising a `ModuleDepsNotMet` exception that both derives from `ImportError` and `unittest.SkipTest`.

Answer (score 1):

Nose has following option:

```
  --doctest-fixtures=SUFFIX
                    Find fixtures for a doctest file in module with this
                    name appended to the base name of the doctest file
```

Perhaps you can isolate fixtures to a separate file?

Comment: Sounds interesting, the important question is if the fixture will be run before the module is imported. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately, `--doctest-fixtures` is only considered for _non-module_ doctests. Therefore, this cannot help me hide `SyntaxError`s during import when doctest searches the modules for tests.Thanks anyways for the answer!